# Are our future deeds written by an Angel while we’re in the womb?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, free-will

In this translation of a Hadith it says:

> Abdullah Ibn Mas’ud reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) who is the most truthful (of the human beings) and his being truthful (is a fact) said:
> Verily your creation is on this wise. The constituents of one of you are collected for forty days in his mother's womb in the form of blood, after which it becomes a clot of blood in another period of forty days. `Then it becomes a lump of flesh and forty days later Allah sends His angel to it with instructions concerning four things, so the angel writes down his livelihood, his death, his deeds, his fortune and misfortune.` By Him, besides Whom there is no god, that one amongst you acts like the people deserving Paradise until between him and Paradise there remains but the distance of a cubit, when suddenly the writing of destiny overcomes him and he begins to act like the denizens of Hell and thus enters Hell, and another one acts in the way of the denizens of Hell, until there remains between him and Hell a distance of a cubit that the writing of destiny overcomes him and then he begins to act like the people of Paradise and enters Paradise. **[ Reference: Sahih Muslim Book 46 Hadith 1 ]**

My question is about the meaning of the Hadith, does it mean the Angel is instructed to write our future deeds while we’re in the womb, or is the angel instructed to record our deeds as we perform them?

Comment: This hadith is regarding Qadr and predestination. It means the angel records all the deeds before they are done. Then, the angels on the left and right record deeds as they happen as well.

Comment: @TheZ if this angel mentioned in this hadith records the deeds before they happen then whats the point of the other angels

Comment: One might as well ask what's the point of angels recording deeds in the first place when Allah knows everything anyway. But, Allah wishes to do things like that.

Comment: To note that this hadith conflicts with another one proclaiming full predestination telling that all has been noted on the preserved tables from the beginning.